# Verification of a condition for an integral property.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

For the property $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx + \int_c^b f(x)\,dx,$$  is the following condition necessary? $$a<c<b?$$ 
I have come across some textbooks that state the above condition to be necessary for the property to hold, whereas some state otherwise; I would like someone to prove or disprove this condition.

Comment: As long as all the integrals are finite, the condition is not necessary.

Comment: can you elaborate as to why it is not necessary.

Comment: The condition is usually put there to aid learning and intuition, not because it is a formal requirement.

Comment: that makes sense since most of the textbooks I saw this  property in were elementary calculus textbooks.Still could you provide a rigorous proof as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this is true as long as $c$ is finite and each integral exists (regardless of whether $a\lt c\lt b$ holds). This trivially follows from the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) as we would have
$$\int_a^cf(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_c^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x=F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)=F(b)-F(a)=\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Ahh, you were faster than me (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that for $x\in[a,b]$,
$$F'(x)=f(x).$$
Therefore, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$I=\int_a^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(a).$$
On the other hand, assuming $c\in[a, b]$, we have the two integrals
$$\begin{align}
I_1&=\int_a^c f(x)dx=F(c)-F(a)&\\
I_2&=\int_c^b f(x)dx=F(b)-F(c).&
\end{align}$$
If you add the two together,
$$I_1+I_2=F(c)-F(a)+F(b)-F(c)=F(b)-F(a)=I.$$